# How to view Flutter debug console output for a release version of the app?

Tags: flutter, dart

Using print() to log messages works in debug mode and I can see output in debug console of VSCode or in terminal. How can I get those with release build ? I have seen release build producing such logs but not sure how to get those.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Run

```
$ flutter logs
```

in terminal with terminal opened in a flutter project directory, connect phone with computer and use the release version of the app on phone to see logs similar to the debug version shows.

***Edit**: Not sure if this works for iOS.*

Comment: Please Elaborate what are you trying to say here? A released version of the app is not connected to any console. So, where to write that command. Or first connect the mobile device to a system and run flutter logs in the console?

Comment: Just connect the phone to the computer, open the app, and run this command in the terminal.

Comment: @TahaMalik, Run this command in terminal, connect phone & run the release version of the app & it shows logs like in debug mode.

Comment: Does this work with iPhones? Sorry I could not find much documentation about it

Comment: This does not seem to work on IOS

Comment: i confirm that it does not work on ios

Comment: not working in ios

Comment: awesome. quite helpful. THanks - works in android