# Flutter stuck at splash screen in release mode and works fine in debug mode

Tags: flutter, dart

I made my own splash screen and have a function in it called `_navigate` which decides where should the user navigate to next, home screen or auth screen.

the problem is that it works fine in debug mode the navigation happens correctly according to the conditions specified, but in release mode it gets stuck and doesn't navigate at all.

here's the code:

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  bool _firstTime = true;

  Future<void> _navigate(BuildContext context) async {
    bool _isLoggedIn = await Provider.of<Info>(context, listen: false).token();

    if (_isLoggedIn) {
      final _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      User _user = User(
        id: _prefs.getString("id"),
        name: _prefs.getString("name"),
        phoneNumber: _prefs.getInt("phoneNumber"),
      );

      Provider.of<Info>(context, listen: false).setUser(user: _user);
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(AuthScreen.routeName);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    if (_firstTime) {
      _navigate(context);
      _firstTime = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.lightGreen,
            ),
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          child: Image(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/freelance.png"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here's the `token` function:

```
Future<bool> token() async {
    final _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _token = _prefs.getString("token");
    return _token != null;
  }
```

and `setUser` function:

```
void setUser({
    @required User user,
  }) {
    _user = user;
  }
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63618065) and look if there's any error

Comment: @LucasJosino okay, thanks, I'll try it now